# Best Practice for Solve "An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager" Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Surely You know why below error occures

> *An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same
>   key.*

its my Entity that I want to Update Or Delete it

```
var p = new Person() // for delete
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "A",
            Family = "A",
            Age = 10
        };
var p2 = new Person() // for update
        {
            Id = 3,
            Name = "W",
            Family = "W",
            Age = 90
        };
```

my goal is use below code but when use it above error occures

```
var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().Attach(p); // maybe not needed !!! according to @oerkelens comment
        leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted; // for delete
        leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified; // for update
        leitner.SaveChanges();
```

so I must change it such as below code

```
var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);

        attachedEntity.Name = "W"; // for update
        attachedEntity.Family = "W";// for update
        attachedEntity.Age = 90;// for update

        leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;// for delete

        leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;// for update

        leitner.SaveChanges();
```

new code works but have two problems for me

**First :** I must search ID handly

```
SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3) // for update or delete
```

**Second :** I must set values to properties one by one

```
        attachedEntity.Name = "W"; // for update
        attachedEntity.Family = "W";// for update
        attachedEntity.Age = 90;// for update
```

I cant assign my entity to attachedEntity

```
attachedEntity = p; // does not work same error as above occures
attachedEntity = p2; // does not work same error as above occures
```

please guide me to access to my goal

my goal is like this :

```
 var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().Attach(p); // may be not needed !!!

        leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted; // if only use this line above error occures again

     leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Modified; // if only use this line above error occures again

        leitner.SaveChanges();
```

set whole of "p" (Entity) at once and no need one by one setting

Comment: First, why would yuo set properties of an entity you want to delete? Secondly, where does your "p" come from? If that is already an attached entity (meaning you retrieved it from your repository, yuo should not try to attach it again, simply delete it if you want that.

Comment: for delete you right !!! but there is two scenarios what for update ?!! - I add update scenario to my post yes you right I delete attach in my sample code but above error occures leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;leitner.SaveChanges();

Comment: For update, setting the properties makes sense.
But yuo still do not want to attach your entity twice. So you get your entity from your context, change the properties, and save your context changes. If you get your entity from your context, attach it again, and try to save it will go wrong. Normally you only attach an entity to your context manually if it came from somewhere else, not from your context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the code to find the entity although you should note that `.Local` will only work if the entity has been previously fetched from the database or attached elsewhere in the current session.

```
var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);
```

There's the `Remove` method on `DbSet`

```
leitner.Set<Person>().Remove(attachedEntity);
```

And the `SetValues` method on the `DbEntityEntry<Person>` that is returned from `leitner.Entry(attachedEntity)`

```
var p2 = new Person() // for update
    {
        Id = 3,
        Name = "W",
        Family = "W",
        Age = 90
    };
leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).Currentvalues.SetValues(p2);
```

Comment: When I use  leitner.Set<Person>().Remove(p);
            leitner.SaveChanges();  Show error : The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager. so I attach entity again but topic error occures

Comment: @HF does it work with `.Local` as in `var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 3);`?

Comment: yes, this code works ,     var attachedEntity = leitner.Set<Person>().Local.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 5);
            leitner.Entry(attachedEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            leitner.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error message happened when I wanted to check if the object which is going to be updated in the database has a unique field (other than P.K) as follow:

```
ctx.Customers.Select(x => x.CustomerCode == Code).SingleOrDefault();
```

and after that the following code raised the "An object with the same key ..." error:

```
ctx.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
...
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Changing the
`ctx.Customers.Select(x => x.CustomerCode == Code).SingleOrDefault();`
to
`ctx.Customers.AsNoTracking().SingleOrDefault(x => x.CustomerCode == Code);`
fixed the problem!